# Как убрать зуммирование сайта пальцами на мобильной версии, но разрешить зуммировать только определенные блоки?

Tags: javascript, html5

Как убрать зуммирование сайта пальцами на мобильной версии, но разрешить зуммировать только определенные блоки?

Comment: Если добавить мета тег `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`, то можно только запретить зуммирование только по всему сайту, задать для блоков нельзя

Comment: тут наверное имеется в виду, как в инстаграмме, там фотки можно зумить (раскрываются как дайтбокс), если пальцами раздвинуть фотку.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже было сказано выше, вам нужно добавить в заголовки "initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" для запрета зума страницы. Далее у нужных блоков повесить обработчик на события touch и делать зум.